# Adding more than one child to jTree

Tags: java

I have the the following jTree code, this code is working with one child then adds grandchild under but i need to create a child then add another child under then add finally the grandchild.

how can I do that?

```
 @SuppressWarnings("CallToThreadDumpStack")
public DefaultMutableTreeNode processHierarchy(Object[] hierarchy) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(hierarchy[0]);
    try {
        int ctrow = 0;
        int i = 0;
        try {

            try {
                con = Database.getConnection();
                stm = con.createStatement();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            String sql = "SELECT catid, catname from category";
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                ctrow = rs.getRow();
            }
            String L1Nam[] = new String[ctrow];
            String L1Id[] = new String[ctrow];
            ResultSet rs1 = stm.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs1.next()) {
                L1Nam[i] = rs1.getString("catname");
                L1Id[i] = rs1.getString("catid");
                i++;
            }
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child, grandchild;
            for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < L1Nam.length; childIndex++) {
                child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(L1Nam[childIndex]);
                node.add(child);//add each created child to root
                String sql2 = "SELECT scatname from subcategory where catid= '" + L1Id[childIndex] + "' ";
                ResultSet rs3 = stm.executeQuery(sql2);
                while (rs3.next()) {
                    grandchild = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(rs3.getString("scatname"));
                    child.add(grandchild);//add each grandchild to each child
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return (node);
}
```

Comment: So, let me clear the questuion: you wanna recursively fetch the rows based on parent id and then convert them into a tree. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: Split the method, first one is for root, second one is for fetch child recursively. Second method take parent id to find its child and self-call based on its return. Next call will fetch the child's child, so call grand child. add returns as child of parent. because you never accept previous questions, I will not waste of my time for writing some code.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't know about Accepting an answer, I'm new to this site, I just post a question and sometimes I get an answer and sometimes not. If there is something to be done, appreciate if someone tells me.